# Convert SQL query to Pig query

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-pig

I am working w/ Pig in Hadoop and have need to convert the following SQL code to PigLatin:

```
SELECT lo_discount, COUNT(lo_extendedprice)
FROM lineorder
GROUP BY lo_discount;
```

After loading the `lineorder` table, this is what I've got so far, but unfortunately it is not working:

```
data = FOREACH lineorder GENERATE lo_discount, lo_extendedprice;
dataG = GROUP data BY lo_discount;
ans0 = FOREACH dataG GENERATE dataG.lo_discount, COUNT(dataG.lo_extendedprice);
```

Can anyone help me how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the last pig statment to

```
ans0 = FOREACH dataG GENERATE group, COUNT(data);
```